# Knockout computed of observables in observableArray

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Is it possible to have an object inside an observableArray that's a computed value of other observables within the same object? I have the following array:

```
self.drug_costs_table = ko.observableArray([
        {
            label: ko.observable('salad'),
            cost_per_dose: ko.observable('123'),
            administrations: ko.observable('9'),
            discount: ko.observable('10'),
            cost_per_year: ko.computed(function () {
                // administrations * cost per dose
            })
        }
]);
```

The observableArray will be built dynamically in the HTML and the final column is drug cost x administrations. Is it possible to have this value in the array or will something have to be done outside of the array to compute the cost_per_year?

This is my HTML:

```
<!-- ko foreach: drug_costs_table -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="grid_4"><label data-bind="text: label"></label></div>
        <div class="grid_2"><input class="total-val" data-bind="decimal: cost_per_dose"></div>
        <div class="grid_2"><input data-bind="number: administrations"></div>
        <div class="grid_2"><input data-bind="percentage: discount"></div>
        <div class="grid_2"><input class="total-val" data-bind="decimal: cost_per_year"></div>
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Any help/advice on this would be greatly appreciated; I'm still a bit of a newbie to knockout!

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VWc8e/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible. But I think you will be better of defining a view model for the drug cost entity.

```
function drugCot(label, cost_per_does, administrations, discount) {
   var self = this;
    self.label = ko.observable(label),
    self.cost_per_dose = ko.observable(cost_per_does),
    self.administrations = ko.observable(administrations),
    self.discount = ko.observable(discount),
    self.cost_per_year = ko.computed(function () {
         return  self.administrations() *  self.cost_per_year();
    })
}
```

And then you can use it inside of your view model that contains self.drug_costs_table to add new costs.

```
self.durg_costs_table.push(new drugCost('salad', 123, 9, 10));
```

**EDIT**

Whenever you now update the self.administrations or self.cost_per_year observables your cost_per_year computed will be updated.

```
var drugCost1 = new drugCost('salad', 123, 9, 10);
self.durg_costs_table.push(drugCost1);
drugCost1.administrations(15);
// after this line of code cost_per_year will contian new value and will notify all the subscribers and rerender bound html elements
```

Comment: I've got this working, however now my cost_per_year totals don't update when the values of administrations or cost_per_dose is changed in the view? @rwisch45

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VWc8e/2/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to have have KO computed observables within a KO observable array. Nothing would have to be done outside of the array if the computed is only using other variables from the same object in the array.

```
self.drug_costs_table = ko.observableArray([
        {
            label: ko.observable('salad'),
            cost_per_dose: ko.observable('123'),
            administrations: ko.observable('9'),
            discount: ko.observable('10'),
            cost_per_year: ko.computed(function () {
                return parseInt(this.administrations(),10) * parseInt(this.cost_per_dose(),10);
            }, this)
        }
]);
```

#### Edit

The answer from @MyP3uK should be your preferred way of doing this

Comment: You are missing parenthesis + you need to put `self` instead of `this`

Comment: This isn't working? For some reason I'm getting NaN errors for the above. (even with self + () ) @GôTô

Comment: @leaksterrr That's because administrations and cost_per_dose are strings, you need to convert it first

Comment: @GôTô You don't need `self` in this case - check out the [section in the KO docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#managing-this) regarding computed observables titled *Managing this*. In this context, `this` is referring to the parent object, which is the first object in his observableArray (and subsequently each other object in the array)

Comment: @leaksterrr Those variables are strings. Try converting them to integers first, i.e. `parseInt(this.administrations,10)`

Comment: @rwisch45 My bad, didn't see the second arg :) But I don't see how the parenthesis aren't needed

Comment: @GôTô What parenthesis are you referring to?

Comment: None of the above works with parseInt etc. I'm still getting NaN? @GôTô

Comment: @rwisch45 administrations and cost_per_dose are observables.

Comment: @GôTô You're right, edited the post. Sorry about that. leaksterr Try it again with the parenthesis after the observables (to access their underlying values) like GôTô pointed out

Comment: That doesn't work either (one of the first things I tried) as soon as I add parenthesis it breaks the whole view model; let me get a fiddle going.

Comment: @leaksterrr See MyP3uk's answer. Here this refers to drug_costs_table's parent, in which drug_costs_table is not even declared when the computed is created